# Retain selected value for link dropdown upon refresh

Tags: html

[image]How do I retain selected value on page refresh for the following dropdown?

```
 <select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
<option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use jQuery and DOM Storage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

See my example of using session Storage here. http://jsfiddle.net/wBcTk/

I set the selected value on change and retrieve the value on page load. So whilst the user is in session, the dropdown we be selected on their previous selection.

```
var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem");  
$('#dropdown').val(selectedItem);

$('#dropdown').change(function() { 
    var dropVal = $(this).val();
    sessionStorage.setItem("SelectedItem", dropVal);
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your input, really appreciate it. I tried it and my page has this pop up that says null. Something like when I clicked on your example link http://jsfiddle.net/wBcTk/ I have uploaded the printscreen to show you what I meant.

Comment: This is because there is an alert in the javascript example to show the selected value when you reload it. I have updated the link now so that it uses my code above. This sets the dropdown value http://jsfiddle.net/wBcTk/4/

Comment: This even stays there even if I close tab and again visit the page freshly.! How do we avoid that on first page load ?